# What does a red square on a file mean in Intellij? Scala error building project on new machine

Tags: intellij-idea

I am switching to a new mac.  The code in question builds with no errors in IntelliJ on my old box.  It does not build in my newly installed IntelliJ, although I can gradlew build -x test and it builds from the command line

I get the following error when trying to build a newly dowloaded "master" project from our repository.

error: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.

When I look in the Project Structure -> Libraries folder I see that a scala library had a small red box on it (see screenshot)

What does the red box mean?  How could I resolve this?  The file in question appears to be available on my box based on the other panes in the "Libraries" window.  There is no "red square" on the same library on my old box where everything builds correctly.

[image: Image shows "red square" on scala library in Project Structure window]

Comment: This icon indicates the Scala library. It's not a symbol of any error. The actual problem is not related to this icon. Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get help.

Comment: However - on my old machine the scala library does not have this red box - thus my theory that it is a sign of an error.  I appreciate the feedback - I'll go digging and see if I can find more.

Comment: The compile time error I do get (In Intellij only) is this: error: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.  And this error follows: org.gradle.internal.serialize.PlaceholderException (no error message)

Comment: The negative vote confuses me.  Having a question implies a lack of knowledge.  I posted what I knew about the problem without going overboard and providing huge amounts of code that (in the end) didn't affect the issue.  IMHO this was a legitimate question posed with enough information to take "next steps"

Answer (score 1):

THE SOLUTION: In IntelliJ's Preferences window, under "Build, Execution, Deployment" on the Gradle "tab" the Gradle JVM was set to a later version of the JDK.  I set it to "Use Project JDK" and the project compiled successfully.